# What is the proper way to run Jbehave tests in Maven?

Tags: maven-2, integration-testing, jbehave

I am new to JBehave and Maven and am struggling to properly run my JBehave tests. 
From the command line, which is the proper command:

```
mvn integration-test
```

or

```
mvn jbehave:run-stories-as-embeddables
```

When I run the [Etsy tutorial example](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial) with "mvn integration-test", it shows 'BUILD SUCCESS' even though there are 2 stories (Etsy Cart and Etsy Browse) that throw Exceptions. The JBehave HTML report shows the errors, but they are not shown in the console (ie., the BUILD SUCCESS I already mentioned). I am also going to integrate with Jenkins, so I need it to also report it on the console (or not?)

Anyhow, How can I properly run JBehave tests with Maven on the CLI so that it fails (but does not stop) when any of the tests fails and reports so on the CLI?

PS. I know there is one other similar question here on SO, but it just points to the tutorial, resulting in what I see above. Thanks!